# PHP Operator / IF Statement not working correctly

Tags: php

I have a problem, I want to check if all my fields aren't empty, I wanna do this in a single if statement, but there is a problem, it only works if both fields return empty, then I get the response returned which I call back in another file, but if one is empty, it doesn't return anything or a NULL. If I use a && (AND) operator it does work, can anyone explain me why and what is wrong?

```
if (!empty($voornaam) || !empty($achternaam)) {
} else {
    $response = [
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => "Check nog even of alle verplichte velden ingevuld zijn!"
    ];
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: `x || y` is true if either of the conditions is true. So your `if` will succeed if either of the fields is not empty. But you want to test that ALL the fields are not empty.

Comment: You are using an OR operator  `||` .. So if **either** or **both** are empty, you will reach your `else`  -- The `AND` operator .. `&&` asks for **both** to be not empty explicitly without exception.

Comment: And realistically .. You should be using: `if (empty($voornaam) || empty($achternaam)) {`  and remove your `else` statement since there is no "action taken" inside the `if`.

Comment: @Zak I suspect he just left that code out to make it a minimal example.

Comment: Either way , it could just be the single if ..  With the rest of the code below the statement should the condition not be met ..  I see no need for an else either way.